# Finitely repeated games

Tags: game-theory

Consider the following matrix game:

\begin{matrix}
 & L &M&R \\
  T&8,8 & 0,9 & 0,0 \\
  C&9,0 & 0,0 & 3,1 \\
  B&0,0 & 1,3 & 3,3
 \end{matrix}

For the twice repeated version of this game, describe a subgame perfect equilibrium in which $(T,L)$ is played in the first round.

So suppose  $(T,L)$ is played in the first round. My book gives the following matrix for second round play:

\begin{matrix}
 & L &M&R \\
  T&B,R & C,R & C,R \\
  C&B,M & B,R & B,R \\
  B&B,M & B,R & B,R
 \end{matrix}

How am I supposed to interpret this second matrix? I was thinking of something like this, Suppose $(T,M)$ is played in round 1. Both players observe the other player's move. Player 1 sees Player 2's choice of $M$ and realizes that if he were to switch to playing $C$ than he could potentially increase his payoff to 9 if Player 2 plays $L$ in the second round , if Player 2 does not play L, then Player 1 is either getting a payoff of 0 or 3, both which are not worse than his previous result. Therefore Player 1 should switch to $C$. Similarly, Player 2 should switch to $R$, since all three scenarios are either better or not worse for him. Is this interpretation correct? We could also argue that $L$ is a dominated strategy which might make things easier.

Comment: Is the second matrix part of the problem or part of the solution?

Comment: Part of the solution. My book says that the optimal strategies for play in the second round is given by the second matrix

Comment: I think I get it now. _Given_ the submitted second-round response matrix _being known_ to both players _in advance_, it is optimal for them to play $(T,L)$ in the first round. (NB: The submitted second-round response matrix only contains Nash play.) So, I guess that means $(T,L)$ and the second matrix _together_ form a subgame-perfect equilibrium. This needn't be unique, but the question asks for "a", not "the", subgame-perfect equilibrium.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if you are also doing other exercises from, presumably, Peters' book, you might look up the errata on his [homepage](http://www.personeel.unimaas.nl/H.Peters/). E.g., there was one change in the same Problem 4.8 (but not relevant to the issue discussed here by us).

Comment: @Transmissionfrom Please answer this question with your comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>At the request of a commenter, I'll post my comment (slightly edited) as an answer. Note that I made up the term "response matrix".</sup>

*Given* the submitted second-round response matrix *being known* to both players *in advance*, it is optimal for them to play $(T,L)$ in the first round. Also the submitted second-round response matrix only contains Nash equilibria. So, I guess that means $(T,L)$ and the second matrix *together* form a subgame-perfect equilibrium. This needn't be unique, but the question asks for "a", not "the", subgame-perfect equilibrium.